# Matching against regexes with bash, output is in the wrong ordering

Tags: regex, bash

I have text file that need to be processed so it will return desired output.

```
hostname ABC1234567
NAME: "Chassis", DESCR: "Nexus5020 Chassis"
PID: N5K-C5020P-BF     , VID: V04 , SN: SSI13390FZT

NAME: "Module 1", DESCR: "40x10GE/Supervisor"
PID: N5K-C5020P-BF     , VID: V04 , SN: JAF1344BHNK

NAME: "Module 2", DESCR: "6x10GE Ethernet Module"
PID: N5K-M1600         , VID: V01 , SN: JAB1228018M

NAME: "Module 3", DESCR: "8x1/2/4G FC Module"
PID: N5K-M1008         , VID: V01 , SN: JAB1231020C
```

I've tried using regex to pass the value to $host variable but it's failed based on the output.

```
#!/bin/bash

re_descr='DESCR: "([^"]+)"'
re_sn='SN: ([^[:space:]]+)'
re_host='hostname ([^"]+)'

while read -r; do
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_descr ]]; then
                descr=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                continue
        fi
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_sn ]]; then
                sn=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_host ]]; then
                host=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi
        if [[ $descr && $sn ]]; then
                printf '%s\t%s\n' "$host"-"$descr","$sn"
                unset -v host descr sn
        fi
done < <(cat file.txt)
```

Right now it will print

```
-Nexus5020 Chassis,SSI13390FZT
-40x10GE/Supervisor,JAF1344BHNK
-6x10GE Ethernet Module,JAB1228018M
-8x1/2/4G FC Module,JAB1231020C
```

How do I get it work so it will print in this format

```
ABC1234567-Nexus5020 Chassis,SSI13390FZT
ABC1234567-40x10GE/Supervisor,JAF1344BHNK
ABC1234567-6x10GE Ethernet Module,JAB1228018M
ABC1234567-8x1/2/4G FC Module,JAB1231020C
```

Comment: Side note: `done < <(cat file.txt)` is the same as `done < file.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all just logic bugs, not issues with bash itself. Compare to the following working code, which you can see in operation at https://ideone.com/mLj5ia:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

re_descr='DESCR: "([^"]+)"'
re_sn='SN: ([^[:space:]]+)'
re_host='hostname ([^"]+)'

while IFS= read -r line; do line=${line%$'\r'}
    [[ $line =~ $re_descr ]] && descr=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    [[ $line =~ $re_sn ]]    && sn=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    [[ $line =~ $re_host ]]  && host=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    if [[ $descr && $sn ]]; then
        printf '%s-%s,%s\n' "$host" "$descr" "$sn"
        descr= sn=
    fi
done
```

- We don't want to `continue` after a `descr` is matched, because `sn` can be on the same line.
- You don't want to `unset host` (or otherwise clear the `host` variable between lines of output), because you want to reuse the same hostname definition repeatedly.
- You want output with dashes and commas, not tabs, so don't use `\t` in the `printf` line; and make sure the number of `%s` sigils matches the number of non-format-string arguments.
- `line=${line%$'\r'}` explicitly strips any trailing carriage returns from the input.

Comment: Thanks, but I encountered some issue with the output result. When I use cat it will still appear as <empty>-<descr>,<sn>

But if I use vim, ^M character will appear after <hostname>

I will figure it out

Comment: `^M` characters are DOS newlines. Easiest thing to do is to make sure that your inputs are valid UNIX text files, and thus end with only LF characters, not CRLF sequences.

Comment: You could also use `while IFS=$'\r' read ...` to have the `read` command trim ^M.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I did that in [an earlier version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54186950/2) and the OP still reported trouble, so I threw my hands up and went the more verbose way. But you're right, that absolutely should work.